# Cannot prevent execution of code in Java

Tags: java, syntax

I have written a program where you write to the console and the program will tell you if the expression is arithmetically correct. Say input is `(12+1)`, output will be `true`.

Now here is a piece of code I found on the internet that will additionally calculate the solution of `(12+1)`. However, I cannot control its execution. I only want it executes if the output is `true`. How can I do that? Here is what I have tried but the code is executed anyway:

Let me clarify; the `if` is executed although `bool` is `false`

I hope you can tell me how to fix it? Because I need this for another, longer code.

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class Supporter{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException{
        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        String str = "2+2";
        int counter=0;
        boolean bool=false;

        if(bool=true){
            System.out.println(engine.eval(str));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use '==' to test for equality.  '=' assigns.

Comment: @JimmyM. Oh wow that helped, thank you :)
Though I'm surprised it wasn't show as error..

Comment: Adding to @ajimenez answer: If your variable is already a `boolean` you can directly use it and don't need to compare it anymore, because that only evaluates to another `boolean`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a small bug: You have to use **==** instead of **=**

```
if(bool == true){
    System.out.println(engine.eval(str));
}
```

Comment: Thank you this helped :) Maybe you can also tell me why it wasn't shown as error that I didn't use double equal sign? In many other cases it is shown, as example when we compare integers.

Comment: Yep and even better : `if(bool)`

Comment: It wasn't shown an error because is not an error:
"=" operator return the value assigned, so you can do thinks like:
    int var1;
    int var2 = (va1 = 10); or int var2 = var 1 = 10;
So var1 and var2 has value 10; 
For boolean case is the same: 
if(bool = true) is equals to do:
boole = true;
if(bool) ... 
I hope I've explained well.